# Seeking Tutorials for GeoMedia?

Tags: references, geomedia

Does anyone know good resources to learn GeoMedia Professional?

I am looking for resources which can serve from a future teaching perspective, but other kinds of resources are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tutorials GeoMedia Professional**

http://outreach.cast.uark.edu/east/toolkit-cast/geospatial_technologies/intergraph_geomedia/tutorials.html

http://geomediawiki.org/Tutorials

Comment: The first link is not working.

Comment: seems the url is correct but the service is unavailable - solution use google cache - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Foutreach.cast.uark.edu%2Feast%2Ftoolkit-cast%2Fgeospatial_technologies%2Fintergraph_geomedia%2Ftutorials.html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: True but is annoying to type each link with cache.

Comment: Teaching resource - (a quick start and GUI guide)  https://support.hexagongeospatial.com/Tutorials/data/04-Introduction-to-GeoMedia-Desktop.pdf additional material - https://geospatialcommunity.hexagon.com/s/geomedia